# onUpdate change diff or patch value?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I am using the [onUpdate](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/providers_database_.refbuilder#onupdate) event handler in Firebase Cloud Functions for the Realtime Database. Works great and I get the before / after snapshot values from the `change` object, as depicted here :

```
Before change :  { '-M0ONRMFJxvClvoFnHP_': true, '-MNxnG-xnFrYOoU_H0U7': false }
After change :  { '-M0ONRMFJxvClvoFnHP_': true }
```

I am curious if there's an "easy" way to get the diff or patch equivalent for this update operation ? Do I have to dive through the Javascript rabbit-hole and dig up a library (any suggestions ?) or is there a built-in feature inside the `change` object ?

Note : there's a [reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/cloud_functions_.changejson) to a `fieldMask` but I am not really seeing any ways to set this up (doesn't seem documented).

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Well, I didn't find anything too exciting, so I just wrote the following that fits my specific purpose :

```
  let beforeKeys = Object.keys(change.before.val() || {});
  let afterKeys = Object.keys(change.after.val() || {});

  let deletions = [];
  let insertions = [];

  deletions = beforeKeys.filter(item => !afterKeys.includes(item));
  insertions = afterKeys.filter(item => !beforeKeys.includes(item));
```

and then I mapped the elements of each array to an async call for removal and addition to specific references in my realtime DB.

There's probably a more efficient way to achieve this, but that should work for now.

Thanks for coming to my TED Talk.

Comment: The way you did is the right one and is the one mentioned in the [Official Firebase Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta-v1-diff#realtime-database).

Comment: @NibrassH, thanks for the message ! Yeah, I was pretty sure about how to get the before and after snapshots. But I was hoping (one can dream !) that there would be a built-in facility for diff or something similar to what I did to get deletions and insertions -- which is pretty important when you're trying to trigger some other behavior based on what was added or removed during the update. I guess that doesn't exist...

Comment: Yes, Unfortunately, there is no built-in function.